# Home network file shares only work one way

Tags: windows, network-shares, home-networking

I am currently sharing folders on my home network between my desktop PC (Win 7 64) and laptop (Win 7 64), both going to the same switch (Zyxel G5-105B). I'm using the default Windows sharing, but I cannot access my desktop PC from my laptop. It works the other way, though. Here's the full run-through:

1. I can see my desktop PC (`\\JUHA-PC\`) in my desktop PC network locations and by opening it through Explorer, and I can see the currently shared folders
2. On my laptop (`\\JUHA-LAPTOP\`), I can also see the shared folders it has in both Network locations and through Explorer
3. Now, on my laptop, I can also see the desktop PC shared folders through Explorer `\\JUHA-PC\`, and I can transfer files just fine from my desktop to my laptop, but...
4. On my desktop PC, I cannot access the laptop at all. It is not visible in Network locations and I cannot access it through Explorer `\\JUHA-LAPTOP\` (Windows throws the error: *The network path was not found*)

Running `net share` on either computer displays their respective shares like it should.

On both computers, under *Advanced sharing settings*, I have the following (identical) settings:

Home or Work profile
 - Turn on network discovery
 - Turn on file and printer sharing
 - Turn on sharing so anyone with network access can read and write files in Public folders
 - File sharing connections, use 128-bit encryption...
 - Turn off password protected sharing
 - Allow Windows to manage homegroup connections

I'm running Comodo Firewall with pretty much identical settings on both computers.

`File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks` is enabled on both computers' Local Area Connections.

So the question is, how can I get my desktop PC to access the shares on my laptop? As far as I know, it should work with these settings, especially since it already works the other way just fine?

Thanks!

Edit:
I also tried the Map Network Drive method listed here:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/windows-7-network-error-code-0x80070035-windows/84791143-b70a-4ec2-b700-98df657fe45c

With both the IP and the computer name, but it also would not connect. I also tried the usernames of both domains/workgroups. No connection.

Comment: Ah, there is a Network Engineering SE, where this fits better. I flagged this for migration.

Comment: This isn't a network engineering question either. It's a home network question and belongs on [SU].

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: Have you tried accessing your Laptop via the IP address, instead of the hostname?

Comment: @Jeeva that gives an "Unspecified error" with a non-descript error code 0x80004005. On a browser, it gives an Unable to connect error (Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 88.195.208.1.). Ping gets a response immediately from both computers, though.

Comment: Network path not found can mean a lot of different things. Normally I'd do some general testing at this point just to gather more information: can you connect by IP instead of hostname? can you connect via other methods (remote desktop, telnet)? what does a pcap show (take one on both sides filtering by IP and compare a connection attempt from both sides). Does it work if you disable the firewall? Basically, just start ruling out variables until you have a more specific problem statement.